# Android HttpUrlConnection passing header params

Tags: java, android, http, header, httpurlconnection

I searched other topics and there were some answers but I didn't succeed to solve my problem.
I have this code and I want to add "Referer" to my http headers.
After using setRequestProperty method, I log the results in Logcat but I don't see referer in the output. what am I doing wrong?

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.example.com");
for(int i=0;con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)!=null;i++){
    String headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
    String headerValue = con.getHeaderField(i);
    Log.d("Header", headerName + ": " + headerValue);
}
```

I also have another code which is not working either:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String IRNIC = cookies.get("IRNIC");
String ROUTEID = cookies.get("ROUTEID");
String myCookies = "IRNIC="+IRNIC+"; ROUTEID="+ROUTEID;
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookies);
for(int i=0;con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)!=null;i++){
    String headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
    String headerValue = con.getHeaderField(i);
    Log.d("Header", headerName + ": " + headerValue);
}
```

For the first code, I don't see referer in the output and also for the second code, I don't see cookies too.
So it seems setRequestProperty is not working!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I can see headers in the output but not the ones I added via setRequestProperty method. so the if code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

**getHeaderFields**

> Returns an unmodifiable map of the **response**-header fields and values

**setRequestProperty**

> Sets the value of the specified **request** header field.

Request is not the same as response. That's why your headers are different. The request will have correct headers using `setRequestProperty`